# MySQL：lft・rgtのツリー構造のテーブルで、子要素がルートから何階層離れているかをselect時に求めたい

Tags: mysql, sql

テーブル情報
- id
   自動採番値
- parent_id
   親idを指定
- root_id
   ツリーのルートのidを指定/ルートレコードである場合はNULL
- lft
- rgt

上記テーブルをselectする際に、子要素がルートから何階層(int)離れているかをSQLで求めたいのですが、方法が分かりません。
ご教授をお願い致します。

また、

```html
order by root_id, lft
```

でツリー構造順に並び替えることが出来るようです。
イメージ：
ルート
　　子要素
　　　子子要素
　　　子子要素
　　子要素

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 からは CTE が使えます
https://yakst.com/ja/posts/4322

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    0 AS depth
  FROM
    some_table

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    T2.id,
    T1.depth + 1
  FROM
    r T1
  CROSS JOIN
    some_table T2
  WHERE
    T1.id = T2.parent_id
)
SELECT id, max(depth) FROM r GROUP BY id ORDER BY id;
```

のようにすることで、親エントリの数を数えることができます

CTE を使えないのであれば、SQLで全件取得し、他プログラムで親を数える以外に方法がないと思います